# Build h323plus support h264 and h263

Tags: ffmpeg, codec, video-codecs, h.323

Try build H323Plus(latest version) with support H263 and H264 codes.

From config.log found error:

```
/usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-suse-linux/7/../../../../x86_64-suse-linux/bin/ld: /tmp/ccLlS6ND.o: in function `main':
conftest.c:(.text.startup+0x7): undefined reference to `h263p_encoder'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

It seems h263p_encoder not found from avcodec.

FFmpeg(latest 4 version ) build with params:

```
--enable-libx264 --enable-libxvid --enable-libx265 --enable-gpl --disable-x86asm --enable-shared --prefix=/usr --libdir=/usr/lib64
```

This codecs I see from FFmpeg. If execute command ffmpeg --codecs:

```
DEV.L. h263                 H.263 / H.263-1996, H.263+ / H.263-1998 / H.263 version 2 (decoders: h263 h263_v4l2m2m ) (encoders: h263 h263_v4l2m2m )
D.V.L. h263i                Intel H.263
DEV.L. h263p                H.263+ / H.263-1998 / H.263 version 2
DEV.LS h264                 H.264 / AVC / MPEG-4 AVC / MPEG-4 part 10 (decoders: h264 h264_v4l2m2m h264_cuvid ) (encoders: libx264 libx264rgb h264_nvenc h264_v4l2m2m nvenc nvenc_h264 )
```

Can any help please. I try build project from Ubuntu 18.04 and Opensuse 15.0

Answer (score 0):

The H323Plus plugins don't compile with current FFmpeg versions. You need versions form ~2014 of FFmpeg (0.6.x) and x264.